# callback is referencing localized function, so undefined. Workaround?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I believe this is the issue.

I have some object:

```
(function(){

  var call_new_function  = function(){
  // do some stuff: but this is function is undefined when called from callback

  }


   var someObject = new Thing();
   $(some_ele).click(function(){
      var _this = this;
      someObject.doSomething({
       // some values are set up

      },
     callback: call_new_function.call(_this)  <-- this throws an error of undefined
   )
  });

})
```

My feeling is outside of scope here:  call_new_function . Is this a closure issue?

Comment: Should that `callback: ...` be inside the object passed to `doSomething` (i.e., immediately below `// some values are set up`)? It seems to be a syntax error as written here.

Comment: @canon I think you've correctly identified the issue, although `_this` is defined just below the `$(some_ele).click(function(){` line.

Comment: @canon. hmm. this is the concern.. I use that function in a few spots so I don't want to return the function because the function isn't always called via a callback. I think you have identified the issue, let me see if I work it out with the info you have supplied. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @canon Whoops, yep! (My turn not to read the code...) I'll just delete my comment, since your answer covers the same ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're providing a function to `callback`. You're executing your function immediately and returning its value to `callback`.

What you probably want to do is perform `call_new_function.call(_this);` on callback. So, wrap it in an anonymous function like so:

```
callback: function() {
    call_new_function.call(_this);
}
```

Comment: how funny. I did do this initially, except I added "return" before the function declaration.. arghh. I hate newbing it up. Thanks a bunch canon.